# Any Russian Orthodox records of Kamchatka priests around 1800?

Tags: russia, 1800s-decade, church-records, 1790s

Yakov Volkov might have been a priest in Petropavlovsk-Kamchatsky around 1800 or slightly before. The Irkutsk bishop who appointed or sent him might have been Beniamin Bagranskii (1789-1814). The "traveling" or "expedition" church founded by Bering had already been destroyed and rebuilt.

Is there a Church reference that might identify him?

Glenn Farris in "So Far From Home" (2012) named Yakov as a priest and as the father of Osip Volkov. His source is uncited. Perhaps the only primary reference to the elder Volkov in the Latin script is in the Santa Cruz Mission sacramental registers, where Marion Pokriots found it for her essay, "Branciforte's Russian Alcalde."

Comment: Where did you find your original clue?  Please tell us so people won't search for the same source you already have.

Comment: Thanks! You can use the edit link under your question to add that information.

Answer (score 4):

It is difficult question because of the not well working archive system in Russia.
I believe that such books are hold in the "Российском Государственном историческом архиве Дальнего Востока" in the Vladivostok. Their e-mail is 
rgiadv@vladivostok.ru
Another option is State Archive of Kamchatskiy Kray: http://www.rusarchives.ru/state/kamchatskiy-kray/gosudarstvennyy-arhiv-kamchatskogo-kraya

You could try also to use http://www.kamlib.ru/library.php?page=res3
But the Russian language is not easy.